# Grub rescue - unable to set boot partition

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, mount

I don't know how it happens but I became unable to start my system kicking to `grub rescue` command prompt. I know that my system is installed on `/dev/sda6` and `ls` in `grub rescue` shell gives me:

```
(hd0), (hdo,msdos1), (hdo,msdos5), (hdo,msdos6), (hdo,msdos6)
```

So I followed general instruction on how to repair system booting:

```
set root=(hd0,msdos6)
set prefix=(hd0,msdos6)/boot/grub 
insmod normal #this gives an error error: unknown filesystem
```

So I loaded to Ubuntu Live CD and tried to repair grub: I started with `sudo mound /dev/sda6 /mnt`... But this gives another error:
`mount: wrong type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda6, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.`
One more symptom is that in Disks program I can see that `/dev/sda6` is Linux, but under Contents I see `unknown` (where usually we can see the filesystem of partition).

`sudo fdisk -l` output:

```
/dev/sda1 .....  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
...
/dev/sda5 ..... HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda6 ..... Linux
/dev/sda7 ..... Linux swap / Solaris
```

Can I repair my system in some way?

Comment: Looks like there is a problem with the file system on sda6. From the Live CD, first unmount - `sudo umount /dev/sda6`, then run `sudo fsck.ext4 -p /dev/sda6`. Hope that works.

Comment: @mikewhatever Why to use `umount` if I'm unable to **mount** it. Maybe just try the second option you suggested?

Comment: Good point, don't use it. I must have put it there just in case. :~)